# fatal: unable to connect to gerrit.googlesource.com

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04, http-proxy

I am trying to download the manifest file for the AM57xx PD17.1.0 BSP,

But iam getting error like below:

repo init -u https://stash.phytec.com/projects/PUB/repos/manifests-phytec.git -b am57xx -m PD17.1.0.xml

Downloading Repo source from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo

fatal: unable to connect to gerrit.googlesource.com:

gerrit.googlesource.com[0: 74.125.68.82]: errno=Connection timed out

gerrit.googlesource.com[1: 2404:6800:4003:c02::52]: errno=Network is unreachable

repo: error: "git" failed with exit status 128

cwd: /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_ti/.repo/repo

cmd: ['git', 'fetch', '--quiet', '--progress', 'origin',
'+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*', '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*']

fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo'

And i had gone through some solution in stack, but unable to resolve.
Please help me to resolve this issue...

Comment: `Network is unreachable` seems pretty straightforward: your host can't get to their host, presumably because the network is down and/or your administrator prohibits access.

Comment: @torek "*Network is unreachable*" is for not configured IPv6. The real problem is "*Connection timed out*".

Comment: @phd: oops, yes. The timeout indicates something pretty similar though, e.g., an administrative block. Some IPv4 stacks will sometimes switch back and forth between timeout and unreachable errors due to ARP issues as well.